# Why are these three intersection points collinear?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

This is what I found several years ago when I was in middle school:

Suppose we have a circle on a plane and arbitrarily choose four different points on the circle, say $P,A,B,C$. Then draw three circles with center $A,B,C$ and radius $|PA|, |PB|, |PC|$, respectively. The three new circles meet at three crossover points besides $P$, say $D, E, F$.

I was amazed that $D, E, F$ are on the same line. Could someone prove this?

Comment: Concentric circles won't intersect one another unless they completely coincide. And circles that intersect usually do so in _two_ points, not one point. So unless I'm missing something, $D, E$ and $F$ don't seem to exist.

Comment: I believe you mean that the three new circles have centers $A$, $B$, $C$ (not $P$). ... In any case, please edit your question to include what you've tried and where you got stuck. I'll note that a quick GeoGebra sketch seems to bear out the (adjusted) result.

Comment: @Arthur:  I believe $P$ is not the center of the circle, but lies ON the circle.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork "Then draw three circles with center $P$ [...] The three new circles meet"

Comment: @Blue I read your correction suggestion, then tried in GeoGebra, but wrong circle intersections and discovered something else cool: The non-$P$ intersection between the original circle and the circle centered at $A$, the non-$P$ intersection between the circles centered at $A$ and at $B$, and the point $B$ itelf seem to be collinear as well.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork P is on the original circle, but the center of the new circles.

Comment: @Blue You are right. The centers are $A,B,C$, not $P$, and I have edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for your pointing out the problem. I have editted the question.

Comment: I have confirmed the adjusted result (and @Arthur's variant) with some coordinate bashing in *Mathematica*. The formulas for the points and line(s) are pretty nice, which suggests there may be an elegant geometric argument.

Comment: Fun Fact: The orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$ is on the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert around point P. Let $X'$ denote the image of the point $X$ under this inversion. We find that $(A'B'C')$ is a straight line, and the circles with centers $A,B,C$ and passing through $P$ are mapped to perpendicular bisectors of the segments $PA',PB',PC'$ respectively, call the perpendicular bisectors $p_a,p_b,p_c$ respectively. Now let the midpoint of the segments $PA',PB',PC'$ be $R,S,T$ respectively. obviously $R,S,T$ are collinear and $R-S-T$ is parallel to $A'-B'-C'$. Let $p_a\cap p_b=D',p_b\cap p_c=E', p_a\cap p_c=F' $. Then we have, in the geometry of the attached figure, that $\angle F'PR= \angle F'TR=\angle E'TS=\angle E'PS\implies \angle E'PF'=\angle SPR +\angle E'PS-\angle F'PR=\angle SPR$. also note that $\angle E'D'F'=\angle SD'R=180^{\circ}-\angle SPR$ because $D'SPR$ is cyclic. Hence $\angle E'PF'+\angle E'D'F'=\angle SPR+ 180^{\circ}-\angle SPR=180^{\circ}$ Hence $PE'D'F'$ is cyclic. Inverting back, we see that $D-E-F$ is a straight line as desired. Other configurations are handled similarly. [image: diagram]

Answer (score 1):

The points $D$, $E$, $F$ are reflections of $P$ in the side-lines of $\triangle ABC$, so the midpoints of segments $PD$, $PE$, $PF$ are the feet of the perpendiculars from $P$ to those side-lines. Those feet are "known" to be collinear, determining the [Simson line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_line).

Consequently, the original line is the dilation of the Simson line in $P$ with scale factor $2$.

[image]